# Create clone of jackson ObjectMapper Instance

Tags: java, jackson

I'm writing a library that needs a `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` instance. The user of the library should be able to provide the configuration for the ObjectMapper or the ObjectMapper instance itself. But I also add/modify some settings of the serializer without affecting the users ObjectMapper instance.

Is there any way to create a copy/clone of ObjectMapper instance?

It looks like `ObjectMapper clonedInstance = new ObjectMapper(originalMapper.getFactory())` could work. But I'm not sure if there is anything what I'm missing. Will the ObjectMapper behave exactly as the original one?

Currently this is my code:

```java
public MyLibraryClass {
    private ObjectMapper internalMapper;

    public MyLibraryClass(ObjectMapper mapper) {
        if (mapper == null) {
            internalMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        } else {
            internalMapper = new ObjectMapper(mapper.getFactory());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `class YourMapper extends ObjectMapper` and write your own features

Comment: The .copy() method of ObjectMapper provides the functionality you requested.

Comment: But thats not what I want. I want that someone can provide the existing ObjectMapper and I want to modify it (like adding `objectMapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(...)`). I am not asking how to extend an ObjectMapper. I am asking how to create a clone of an existing instance

Comment: @groovedigga thanks! Somehow I didn't see this

Comment: @Raman: Glad that I could help. Please upvote comments that add something useful to your question.

Comment: @groovedigga I already upvoted your comment

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`ObjectMapper#copy()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#copy()):

> ### `copy`
>
> ```
> public ObjectMapper copy()
> ```
>
> Method for creating a new `ObjectMapper` instance that has same initial
>   configuration as this instance. Note that this also requires making a
>   copy of the underlying `JsonFactory` instance.
>
> Method is typically used when multiple, differently configured mappers
>   are needed. Although configuration is shared, cached serializers and
>   deserializers are NOT shared, which means that the new instance may be
>   re-configured before use; meaning that it behaves the same way as if
>   an instance was constructed from scratch.
>
> Since:
>   2.1

Example:

```
public MyLibraryClass {
    private ObjectMapper internalMapper;
    public MyLibraryClass(ObjectMapper mapper) {
        if (mapper == null) {
            internalMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        } else {
            internalMapper = mapper.copy();
        }
    }
}
```

Also see this observation from the [`ObjectMapper` class javadocs](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html):

> (...) method `copy()` which creates a clone of the mapper with specific
>   configuration, and allows configuration of the copied instance before
>   it gets used. Note that `copy()` operation is as expensive as
>   constructing a new `ObjectMapper` instance: if possible, you should
>   still pool and reuse mappers if you intend to use them for multiple
>   operations.